# How to set string array inversely on android spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, arrays

I have an string array like this:`

```
   <string-array name="converterlist">
        <item>Angle</item>
        <item>Area</item>
        <item>Bits and Bites</item>
        <item>Density</item>
        <item>Electric Current</item>
        <item>Energy</item>
        <item>Force</item>
        <item>Length</item>
        <item>Mass</item>
        <item>Power</item>
        <item>Pressure</item>
        <item>Speed</item>
        <item>Temperature</item>
        <item>Time</item>
        <item>Volume</item>
    </string-array>
```

When I set it on an android spinner, it is showing as it is on the array. Now, I have another spinner where I want to set the list reverse or from second item. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you post the relevant spinner code? And have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

In your onCreate method for the activity that has the spinner, load the string array from resources `getResources().getStringArray(...)`, reverse that array, and set it as the data source to the reverse spinner using an ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
String[] arr=getResources.getStringArray(R.id.converterlist);

//reversed list
List<String> convertList=Collections.reverse(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr)));
```